# Finding duplicate files by name ignoring the case in subdirectories

Tags: find, filenames, duplicate, case-sensitivity

How is it possible to list duplicate file names on a Linux system

- ignoring the case
- including all subdirectories

Files should not be compared by their **content** but only by their **names**.
The output should be a list of file names including the path, so that one can run further commands on these files.

Lets assume we have

```
ls -1R /tmp/
foo
BAR
barfoo
a/BAr
a/b/bar
c/bAr
```

The output of the filter/find script should be

```
/tmp/BAR
/tmp/a/BAr
/tmp/a/b/bar
/tmp/c/bAr
```

Comment: What do you mean by **Files should not be compared by their content by intention**. So, if you have `file1` and `file2` with exact same contents, do you want them to be listed or not listed?

Comment: may be some `find . -print | sed ` is the right strategy...

Comment: Well, if you are on an ubuntu machine [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/48556/334241) might help.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -printf "%p %f\n" | sort -f -k2 | uniq -Di -f1
```

Specify your choice of starting directory for `find` if you don’t want to start at **`.`**. 
Add `-type f` if you want just *file* names.

- The `find` command produces a list of file (and directory) names, in directory order (i.e., random order, as far as you’re concerned).
- `-printf "%p %f\n"` prints the full pathname (relative to `.`) and the filename.
- `sort -f` is short for `sort --ignore-case`, i.e., it sorts the filename list in a case-insensitive way
- `-k2` tells it to use the second field as the sort key.
- `uniq -Di -f1` is short for `uniq --all-repeated --ignore-case --skip-fields=1`, i.e., it shows (all) the lines of output from `find` that occur repeatedly, based on case-insensitive comparison of the second field and beyond (i.e., that have the same (case-insensitive) file name).

This should give you the output that you want, except each line will have the filename repeated at the end.  If you want to get rid of that, pipe into `sed 's/ .*//'`.

A couple of gotchas:

- If you have *directories* whose names are the same except for case,
  and they contain files whose names are the same except for case, e.g.,

  ```
  documents/design.doc
  Documents/Design.doc
  ```

  then these will be listed.
- If you have files (or directories) whose names contain spaces, tabs, or newlines, this will break.

Comment: This won't work. Will only match files where the path and the filename both match (except for case). It won't match `/tmp/BAR` and `/tmp/a/BAr`.

Comment: But the question is not (only) about files in the same directory...

Comment: Well, that was far from obvious until the OP edited the question, which happened while I was typing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works for basic file names, but will not work for files with carriage returns and probably a few other edge cases.

```
FilesNoPath=$(find . -printf "%f\n")
FilesWithPath=$(find .)

oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for filename in $FilesNoPath;
do
    Matches=$(echo "$FilesWithPath" | grep -i "/$filename$")
    if [ $(echo "$Matches" | wc -l) -gt 1 ]
    then
        echo Found matches:
        echo "$Matches"
        FilesWithPath=$(echo "$FilesWithPath" | grep -vi "/$filename$")
    fi
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```

You can replace the `.` in the two find commands with `/path/to/your/files` if you want the output to show the full path and/or you don't want to execute this from within the parent directory of the matching files.

Comment: Don't you need `IFS=$'\n'` so that spaces in filenames won't break the `for` loop?

Comment: @Barmar You're absolutely right. Edited.